# C specifier for printing type pair<size_t, bool>

Tags: c++, c, printf

So I am working on a project which uses C++. I made a multimap and an iterator of the following type-

```
std::multimap < size_t, std::pair<size_t, bool> > position_seqsmapper;
std::multimap < size_t, std::pair<size_t, bool> > :: iterator position_seqsmap_iterator;
```

Now the issue is I need to use printf (cannot use cout because the project has a quite large codebase which is more than 10 years old and that's just the way it is). Now when I try to print this using the code below, it throws an error

```
for (position_seqsmap_iterator = position_seqsmapper.begin(); position_seqsmap_iterator != position_seqsmapper.end(); ++position_seqsmap_iterator)
{
    printf("%lu", position_seqsmap_iterator->first);
    printf("\t");
    printf("%lu", "%d", position_seqsmap_iterator->second);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Gives this error

```
warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘const char*’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%lu", "%d", position_seqsmap_iterator->second);`
```

When I comment out the third line in printf, it works fine. What is the specifier to print out the second element pair in the multimap using printf??

Comment: What do you think that line does exactly? What is the `"%d"` in there for?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, well I have a pair of <size_t, bool>, I thought the %d will specify the bool variable

Comment: Then what's the `"%lu"` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dereferenced, your iterator yields a `pair`, whose `second` member is another `pair`.  `printf()` doesn't know how to print a `pair`, so you have to pass each `first` and `second` member individually to `printf()`.

But, for that `2nd` pair, you are trying to use 2 format strings in a single `printf()` call, which simply will not work.  Your format string is just `"%lu"`, which expects an `unsigned long` as input, but you are giving it a string literal `"%d"` instead, hence the error, and `position_seqsmap_iterator->second` gets ignored.

You need to combine the 2 format strings into 1 format string, eg:

```cpp
for (position_seqsmap_iterator = position_seqsmapper.begin(); position_seqsmap_iterator != position_seqsmapper.end(); ++position_seqsmap_iterator)
{
    printf("%zu", position_seqsmap_iterator->first);
    printf("\t");
    printf("%zu%d", position_seqsmap_iterator->second.first, position_seqsmap_iterator->second.second);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Alternatively, you can merge those 4 `printf()` calls into 1 single call:

```cpp
for (position_seqsmap_iterator = position_seqsmapper.begin(); position_seqsmap_iterator != position_seqsmapper.end(); ++position_seqsmap_iterator)
{
    printf("%zu\t%zu%d\n", position_seqsmap_iterator->first, position_seqsmap_iterator->second.first, position_seqsmap_iterator->second.second);
}
```

Which can then be cleaned up a bit further:

```cpp
for (position_seqsmap_iterator = position_seqsmapper.begin(); position_seqsmap_iterator != position_seqsmapper.end(); ++position_seqsmap_iterator)
{
    const std::pair< size_t, std::pair<size_t, bool> > &elem = *position_seqsmap_iterator;
    const std::pair<size_t, bool> &val = elem.second;
    printf("%zu\t%zu%d\n", elem.first, val.first, val.second);
}
```

And then simplified further if you are using C++11 or later:

```cpp
for (const auto &elem : position_seqsmapper)
{
    const auto &val = elem.second;
    printf("%zu\t%zu %d\n", elem.first, val.first, val.second);
}
```

And further still in C++17 and later:

```cpp
for (const auto &elem : position_seqsmapper)
{
    const auto [first, second] = elem.second;
    printf("%zu\t%zu%d\n", elem.first, first, second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, you may find it more convenient to use `std::cout << ...` rather than `printf`. But you can use `printf` if you prefer.

There is of course no `printf` format specifier for `std::pair<size_t, bool>`. You have to print each member separately.

The `printf` specifier for `size_t` is `"%zu"`. There is none for `bool`, but you can use `%d`, since `bool` will be promoted to `int`.

If you use a C++ stream, you can just pass the members to the output stream.

```
std::pair<size_t, bool> p = ...;
std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
```

By default, a `bool` value is printed as `0` or `1`. You can use the `std::boolalpha` manipulator to print it as `false` or `true`.

If you like, you can define an overloaded `operator<<` operator for your type.